# Random number guessing game VB

Tags: vb.net

OBJECTIVE:

This is a guessing game. The program is to generate a random number between 1 and 500. The user is to guess the number.

The form should include a START button, a listbox to hold all valid guesses, and a label displaying the answer.

Upon clicking the START button, the user will enter a number in response to an InputBox().

If the user’s guess is invalid (not numeric, not a whole number, out of range), display an appropriate message.

If the guess is valid but is not the correct number (high or low), display an appropriate message.

image high quess dialog boximage low quess dialog box

Every time the user guesses a valid numeric guess within range, add the guess to the listbox on the form. Allow the guesses to be shown in multiple columns in the listbox.

If the user successfully guesses the number, display an appropriate message. Include how many guesses they took. Count only valid (in range, integral) numeric guesses as a guess.

Allow the user to quit the game by entering Quit in response to the input box. If the user gives up, tell them the correct number

Important: Display the random number in a label immediately after generating it so that I (and you) know what the number is while I am (and you are) testing it. You can obviously take it out if you really want to play the game.

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    'Declare Variables
    Dim strGuess As String
    Dim random As New Random
    Dim answer As Integer

    'Start with empty Boxes
    lstGuesses.Items.Clear()


    answer = random.Next(1, 500)
    lblAnswer.Text = CStr(answer)

    Do
        Try

            strGuess = InputBox("Enter a numeric integer between 1 and 500. , Enter 'quit' to Quit.", "Guessing Game")
            lstGuesses.Items.Add(strGuess)

            If strGuess = CStr("quit") Then
                MessageBox.Show("The number was " & answer & ". Click Start Game to play again.")
                Exit Do
            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) < CInt(1) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Guess. Enter an Integer Number between 1 and 500!")

            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) > CInt(500) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Guess. Enter an Integer Number between 1 and 500!")

            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) = CInt(answer) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Got it! You guessed " & lstGuesses.Items.Add(strGuess) & " times!")
            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) > CInt(answer) And CInt(strGuess) <= CInt(500) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Guess is High")
            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) < CInt(answer) And CInt(strGuess) >= CInt(1) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Guess is Low")
            End If

            If lstGuesses.Items.Contains("quit") = True Then
                MessageBox.Show("The number was " & answer & ". Click Start Game to play again.")

            End If

        Catch ex As InvalidCastException
            'Make user guess
            MessageBox.Show("Invlid Guess. Enter a numeric integer between 1 and 500!")
        End Try

    Loop While CInt(strGuess) <> answer

End Sub
```

MY PROBLEM:
I have been trying everything and this is the best i have made yet. This homework is due in 4 hours so any help will be appreciated.
I am suppose to type the word "quit" to end the game. But also give an error message when something other than letters are typed. Every time I type a letter and press enter, it gives the warning that i set but then it crashes. It is not supposed to crash. It says the crash is from: 
Loop While CInt(strGuess) <> answer
and the problem is because of an InvalidCastException and says convertion from string to type integer is not valid. I tried doing TRYPARSE but still the same problem. Can anyone tell me how to let me type the word "quit" into the box so that it quits the game, but doesn't make it crash.

Comment: Show us how you “tried doing TRYPARSE” and post the full error message, not just a few words from the message.

Comment: `This homework is due in 4 hours` Software Development 101: the first half of a project takes 80% of the time.  The second half takes the other 80%.  Start earlier next time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code golf question, and thus belongs on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best way but i think it will help.

What you need to do is Make a new if statement at the top just after the user entered something in the inputbox.

```
            If IsNumeric(strGuess) Or strGuess = CStr("quit") Then
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Only Numbers")
                GoTo Line1
            End If
```

And here you check "If IsNumeric(strGuess) Or strGuess = CStr("quit") Then"
if yes do nothing
If No show a msgbox and use a goto "GoTo Line1" "so above your do you add Line1:"

If somebody types something like "a" he will go to line1 "so start the do" and the user needs to enter something new in the inputbox.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

'Declare Variables
    Dim strGuess As String
    Dim random As New Random
    Dim answer As Integer

    'Start with empty Boxes
    lstGuesses.Items.Clear()


    answer = random.Next(1, 500)
    lblAnswer.Text = CStr(answer)

Line1:
    Do
        Try

            strGuess = InputBox("Enter a numeric integer between 1 and 500. , Enter 'quit' to Quit.", "Guessing Game")
            lstGuesses.Items.Add(strGuess)

            If IsNumeric(strGuess) Or strGuess = CStr("quit") Then
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Only Numbers")
                GoTo Line1
            End If

            If strGuess = CStr("quit") Then
                MessageBox.Show("The number was " & answer & ". Click Start Game to play again.")
                Exit Do
            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) < CInt(1) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Guess. Enter an Integer Number between 1 and 500!")

            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) > CInt(500) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Guess. Enter an Integer Number between 1 and 500!")

            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) = CInt(answer) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Got it! You guessed " & lstGuesses.Items.Add(strGuess) & " times!")
            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) > CInt(answer) And CInt(strGuess) <= CInt(500) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Guess is High")
            End If

            If CInt(strGuess) < CInt(answer) And CInt(strGuess) >= CInt(1) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Guess is Low")
            End If

            If lstGuesses.Items.Contains("quit") = True Then
                MessageBox.Show("The number was " & answer & ". Click Start Game to play again.")

            End If

        Catch ex As InvalidCastException
            'Make user guess
            MessageBox.Show("Invlid Guess. Enter a numeric integer between 1 and 500!")
        End Try

    Loop While CInt(strGuess) <> answer
End Sub
```

Comment: Why `CStr("quit")` instead of just `"quit"`?

Comment: @Basic Becaus I copyed it from his code.I just fixed what he asked for.it worked so ,it was good enuf for me.